# Orbeon Forms how to throw an alert

Tags: orbeon

I'm using orbeon forms (PE 4.7) and I have created a output field which is counting the some other fields values and I want to show the alert if the value of output field is less then 100.how can i show alert or error if value is not 100.
Please help me I am struggling with this issue for last one week.

Comment: It seems that somebody replied to you [here](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Orbeon-Forms-how-to-throw-an-alert-td4660361.html).

Comment: Thank you Mr @  ebruchez. Now it is working.